# Regular expression to match valid words at start, end and in the middle of a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have a particular problem with regular expressions. Consider this sentence of valid words:

```
sphere_a [sS]phere_b [sS]pher* [sS]pher* sph[eE]* sphere_a ^sphe* ^sp[hH]er*
```

***I want these words to be split up, so I can use each one separately for operations downstream. To do this I am currently using 2 regular expressions.***

One that matches the word at the start of the sentence:

```
(?<=^)(?P<pattern>[\w\^\?\*\[\]]+)(?=\s|$)
```

and one that matches all the others:

```
(?<=\s)(?P<pattern>[\w\^\?\*\[\]]+)(?=\s|$)
```

---

***It would be nice to know if this could fit in one expression? It would save the looping.***

---

Strangely enough the obvious first try:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?P<pattern>[\w\^\?\*\[\]]+)(?=\s|$)
```

fails with an error:

```
Invalid regular expression: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

---

***I am using Pythons [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module, and [pythex.org](http://pythex.org/) for validation.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your patterns easily with

```
regexs = 'sphere_a [sS]phere_b [sS]pher* [sS]pher* sph[eE]* sphere_a ^sphe* ^sp[hH]er*'.split().
```

Then you can iterate over the patterns like this:

```
for regex in regexs:
    m = re.findall(regex, content)
```

But it will return duplicate matches.

Comment: I believe your approach of splitting is probably much more practical than doing this by regex! **Accepted** - Thanks!